# Communication error, while trying to submit app to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode 5, I have tried to validate my app but these communication errors were found:

Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443.

An exception has occurred:Remote host closed connection during handshake

An error occurred while invoking service method:authicateForTransportDiscovery

An exception has occurred:null

Could not connect to Apple's web service

An error has occurred while invoking service method: validateMetadata

Unable to authenticate the package: 96850972.itmsp

Any ideas?

Comment: how about upgrading to Xcode 6?

Comment: Thanks, i tried what you told me, but a connections error occurs again 'an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made' Is this something to do with my wifi

Comment: Try different network

Comment: If we set parental controls for login to mac we can get this issue as well. Have you tried resolving this further.

Answer (score 2):

I changed to another network and it worked as @Jainam Jhaveri said.

Comment: Did help partially I'd say, on top of this I had to restart Mac.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to use the Transporter app (found on Mac App Store), after creating an archive choose to EXPORT it not upload it, you will get a folder containing 4 files with one of the being the .ipa, from the Transporter select the .ipa and click deliver, worked like a charm, didn't have to reboot or change the network.

Comment: The Transporter solution worked for me too.