# Can't upload .ipa file: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity

Tags: xcode, networking, app-store, expo, xcrun

I'm trying to upload an `.ipa` file generated with `expo`. The Application Loader is no more, so the only way to do this is to use command line.

Here is what I do:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f ~/Downloads/app-645d5380-019e-42a6-aba2-d737e9181221-archive.ipa -u myappleid@gmail.com --password my-app-specific-password --verbose
```

Getting this:

```
Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
```

I've tried all answers from these questions:

- [Very Slow App Upload/Communication Failure - Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177425/very-slow-app-upload-communication-failure-application-loader)
- [App Store Connect Operation Error: Could not connect to Apple's web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695236/app-store-connect-operation-error-could-not-connect-to-apples-web-service)
- [Unable to upload iOS app with Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240579/unable-to-upload-ios-app-with-application-loader)
- [Communication error, while trying to submit app to app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193722/communication-error-while-trying-to-submit-app-to-app-store)
- [itunesconnect using application loader behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/itunesconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall)
- [How to upload IPA now that Application Loader is no longer included in Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976017/how-to-upload-ipa-now-that-application-loader-is-no-longer-included-in-xcode-11)

I've also tried sudo it, turn off the firewall, turn off littlesnitch, turn off VPN, use `-ITunesTransport DAV`. I've tried to use different internet providers: connecting laptop through my phone and even tried to upload from different mac located in a different country. I've tried using xcode 10.3 Application loader.

Full error output:

```
[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main> ERROR: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main> ERROR: Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp
[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main> ERROR: An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main> DEBUG: com.apple.transporter.core.api.UnrecoverableOperationException: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
  at com.apple.transporter.JSONService.invoke(JSONService.java:436)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1244)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1203)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1167)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.authenticateOperation(WebService.java:320)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$3.invoke(Upload.java:801)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$3.invoke(Upload.java:793)
  at com.apple.transporter.core.ws.impl.WebServiceInvokerDefaultImpl.invokeWithRetry(WebServiceInvokerDefaultImpl.java:79)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performAuthenticateOperationForUpload(Upload.java:793)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.validateAssets(Upload.java:550)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:296)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:129)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performRequest(Upload.java:1268)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.execute(Verify.java:120)
  at com.apple.transporter.Application.reallyBegin(Application.java:224)
  at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:114)
  at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.start(TransporterService.java:87)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.runService(TransporterStarter.java:476)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.runTransporterService(TransporterStarter.java:450)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.start(TransporterStarter.java:188)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.runStartable(BootstrapperPhase2.java:355)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.runStarter(BootstrapperPhase2.java:317)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.start(BootstrapperPhase2.java:130)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.startOSGiFramework(BootstrapperPhase1.java:321)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:99)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:59)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Launcher.launchBootstrapper(Launcher.java:37)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:220)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:658)

[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Operation failed","index":3},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}
[2019-10-12 11:14:25 CEST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
2019-10-12 11:14:25.989 altool[6464:70139]  Out:



Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
  /var/folders/2m/vfw1bgqd4pv7hk86kcbvcrlc0000gn/T/4AA8A45F-6127-4FC7-8F55-01708CFCF921/1482820372.itmsp - Error Messages:
    Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
    Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp
    An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
2019-10-12 11:14:25.992 altool[6464:70139] Errors: (
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedDescription=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp, NSLocalizedDescription=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedDescription=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedFailureReason=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.}"
)
2019-10-12 11:14:26.021 altool[6464:70128] *** Error: Errors uploading '/Users/my_user_name/Downloads/app-645d5380-019e-42a6-aba2-d737e9181221-archive.ipa': (
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedDescription=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp, NSLocalizedDescription=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error while processing package 1482820372.itmsp}",
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedDescription=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity., NSLocalizedFailureReason=An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.}"
)
2019-10-12 11:14:26.022 altool[6464:70128] 'IosApplicationArchiveExpander', cleanupDestinationDirectory: '/var/folders/2m/vfw1bgqd4pv7hk86kcbvcrlc0000gn/T/app-645d5380-019e-42a6-aba2-d737e9181221-archive-3.ipa'
2019-10-12 11:14:26.120 altool[6464:70128] Cleaning up files....
2019-10-12 11:14:26.127 altool[6464:70128] Deleted temporary package at '/var/folders/2m/vfw1bgqd4pv7hk86kcbvcrlc0000gn/T/4AA8A45F-6127-4FC7-8F55-01708CFCF921/1482820372.itmsp'.
2019-10-12 11:14:26.127 altool[6464:70128] -[ITunesTransporter dealloc] <ITunesTransporter: 0x7ff236776640>
2019-10-12 11:14:26.129 altool[6464:70128] Deallocating <ITunesSoftwareServiceWorkSeriesFactory: 0x7ff2367744b0>
```

I've tried XCode 10.3 Application Loader too. Here is the error:

```
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main>  INFO: Web service received a server status of: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main>  INFO: Web service response received: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 200;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #4c4c4c;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .section {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">
    <h1>&#63743;</h1>

    <h3>Gateway Timeout</h3>
    <p>Correlation Key: OBSCURED_COZ_IM_NOT_SURE_IF_I_CAN_SHARE_IT</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>


[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main> ERROR: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main> ERROR: Error while processing package 1483762480.itmsp
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main> ERROR: An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main> DEBUG: com.apple.transporter.core.api.UnrecoverableOperationException: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
  at com.apple.transporter.JSONService.invoke(JSONService.java:436)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1244)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1203)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1167)
  at com.apple.transporter.WebService.authenticateOperation(WebService.java:320)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$3.invoke(Upload.java:801)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$3.invoke(Upload.java:793)
  at com.apple.transporter.core.ws.impl.WebServiceInvokerDefaultImpl.invokeWithRetry(WebServiceInvokerDefaultImpl.java:79)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performAuthenticateOperationForUpload(Upload.java:793)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.validateAssets(Upload.java:550)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:296)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:129)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performRequest(Upload.java:1268)
  at com.apple.transporter.operation.Verify.execute(Verify.java:120)
  at com.apple.transporter.Application.reallyBegin(Application.java:224)
  at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:114)
  at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.start(TransporterService.java:87)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.runService(TransporterStarter.java:476)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.runTransporterService(TransporterStarter.java:450)
  at com.apple.transporter.starter.TransporterStarter.start(TransporterStarter.java:188)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.runStartable(BootstrapperPhase2.java:355)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.runStarter(BootstrapperPhase2.java:317)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.start(BootstrapperPhase2.java:130)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.startOSGiFramework(BootstrapperPhase1.java:321)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:99)
  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:59)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Launcher.launchBootstrapper(Launcher.java:37)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:212)
  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:642)

[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Operation failed","index":3},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}
[2019-10-16 15:10:31 CEST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1




Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
  /var/folders/2m/vfw1bgqd4pv7hk86kcbvcrlc0000gn/T/3FBECDBC-4EDE-458A-8F0F-2245871DE732/1483762480.itmsp - Error Messages:
    Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
    Error while processing package 1483762480.itmsp
    An exception has occurred: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976017/how-to-upload-ipa-now-that-application-loader-is-no-longer-included-in-xcode-11

Comment: @Oleg I've tried all of those solutions too. I've also contacted Apple support but didn't hear back from them in 4 days

Comment: what the version of expo sdk did you use?

Comment: @stkvtflw have you had any luck on this? I've tried everything INCLUDING the answer below with no luck at all. I'm worrying that it's something strange with my Xcode project that has to be enabled for React Native rather than an actual networking error! I can upload other apps with absolutely no trouble, just the RN one that's having issues.

Comment: Just found this other question! Solved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977456/communication-error-when-uploading-90-mb-ipa-file-with-swift-to-appstore

Thanks Apple for your super-helpful error messages!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably a network configuration issue, try the following:

1. Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Agents
2. Make sure Automatic Agent Discovery and Automatic Agent Configuration are checked
3. Do not check any other proxy options
4. Make sure `SOCKS Proxy` is unchecked

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by using the Transporter app from Apple. There were no network problems...